# Add PowerAutomate descriptions using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, power-automate

Pretty much the title. I'd like to type out my descriptions in a separate file and use a PS script to apply them to my flows. I know that flows are essentially stored as CRM objects if that helps at all. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, “descriptions” for what?

Comment: PowerAutomate flows. They're automations built in Microsoft's Power Platform
https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/?&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIzo3D8oSy-AIVivOzCh12ewErEAAYASAAEgIBdPD_BwE:G:s&OCID=AID2200053_SEM_EAIaIQobChMIzo3D8oSy-AIVivOzCh12ewErEAAYASAAEgIBdPD_BwE:G:s&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzo3D8oSy-AIVivOzCh12ewErEAAYASAAEgIBdPD_BwE